# Ошибка при скачивании pip install jsonlib

Tags: python, json

Написал в cmd 'pip install jsonlib'.
Вот что мне выдало в командной строке красным шрифтом. Помогите.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\данилыч\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Данилыч\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8gbl2gh1\\jsonlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Данилыч\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8gbl2gh1\\jsonlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Данилыч\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-lgcx0xrv\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\данилыч\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\jsonlib'
     cwd: C:\Users\Данилыч\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8gbl2gh1\jsonlib\
Complete output (9 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win32-3.8
copying jsonlib.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8
running build_ext
building '_jsonlib' extension
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\данилыч\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Данилыч\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8gbl2gh1\\jsonlib\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Данилыч\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-8gbl2gh1\\jsonlib\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Данилыч\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-lgcx0xrv\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\данилыч\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\jsonlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Попробуйте еще `pip install jsonlib-python3`

Comment: Кстати, вам действительно нужен именно jsonlib, или может быть хватит модуля json, который входит в стандартную библиотеку python?

Answer (score 0):

Последняя строка:

> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

У вас не установлен Microsoft Visual C++, или его версия ниже 14.0
Ссылку, откуда его можно скачать, вам также предоставили (он скачивается вместе с другими программами пакета).
Если хотите серьёзно заниматься программированием, пытайтесь читать те ошибки, которые получаете. Текст к ним не просто так выводится.

Comment: Так смысл в том, что у меня 19 версия его стоит((( все равно не работает

Comment: @misle動漫 а что если всё-таки именно 14-ю поставить?